# Solr : How to solve this user case

Tags: solr, lucene, lucene.net, solr4

In Solr 4.* , suppose I have field `"mytext"`.

1. First record in "`mytext`" is "`working at ABC`".
2. Second record in "`mytext`" is "`working at ABC project ABC`".

Now When I am searching for  "`Working at ABC`", then sequence of documents are

**Doc 1**: "`Working at ABC project ABC`"

**Doc 2**: "`Working at ABC`"

Although as per calculations it make sense, Second document should be on top because it contains "ABC" twice (TF higher for second doc).

But from user perspective when query entered "working at ABC" result should be

```
"Working at ABC"

"Working at ABC project ABC"
```

.

How do I handle such scenarios. **This project occur only when "Company" and "Project" have overlapping data. Like in this case its "ABC"**.

Thanks

Amit Aggarwal

Comment: you have to ask yourself why doc2 should have higher rank? it makes more sense to the user but why? otherwise you will keep going in cycles, and in another scenario you would have an opposite case.

Comment: you can always override the similarity class in the schema file, and provide your own implementation for calculating TF, IDF, norms, etc. Which I usually do when there is an odd case.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `omitTermFreqsAndPositions=true`for the field. As long as norms are included, fields with shorter content will be ranked higher than those with longer content.

Comment: I will reindex solr with this field .. I think this could be my answer ... I will let you know .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing schema.xml . I overwrite TF function which always return 1 . Thus no affect of term frequency.

If in case anyone using Solr on short fields then here is my custom class

```
private static float ARR[] = { 0.0f, 1.5f, 1.25f, 1.0f, 0.875f, 0.75f, 0.625f, 0.5f, 0.4375f, 0.375f, 0.3125f};

  /** 
   * Implemented as a lookup for the first 10 counts, then
   * <code>1/sqrt(numTerms)</code>. This is to avoid term counts below
   * 11 from having the same lengthNorm after being stored encoded as
   * a single byte.
   */
  public float lengthNorm(FieldInvertState state) {
    int numTerms = state.getLength();
    String fieldName = state.getName();

    System.out.println("field is " + fieldName  + "   number of terms are  " + numTerms);
    if( numTerms <= 10 ) {
      // this shouldn't be possible, but be safe.
      if( numTerms < 0 ) { numTerms = 0; }

      return ARR[numTerms];
    }
    //else
    return (float)(1.0 / Math.sqrt(numTerms));
  }

  // For short fields , term frequency does not always lead to relevancy so returning 1.0 
  @Override
  public float tf(float freq) {
      return (float) 1.0;
  }
```